# Auto increment session index inside foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo

I have a foreach loop that displays database rows dynamically. I'm displaying them inside a form so when I click the button inside one of the forms that got displayed I go to another page which updates my database based on what form I selected.

My only idea about how I can grab the specific row and update it is by setting a session for each form created; how can I set a session with an auto incrementing index?

```html
<?php foreach($stmt as $row):?>
    <form action="Update.php" method="POST" >
        <p>Has  <?php echo $row["info"]; ?> seat(s) available </p>
        //other similar html elements and echoing from database

        <button type="submit" name="updateData"> Reserve</button>
        // $_SESSION['phone']=$row['phone']
    </form>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

If I leave the session like this, it gets overwritten.

Update.php

```php
$sss=5;

if(isset($_POST['updateData'])){
    
 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE ddd SET seats =:seats where phone = :phone");
    $stmt->bindParam(':seats', $sss);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $_SESSION['phone']);
```

Comment: fix is not to put phone into session and use a form input, with an row id and the seat numbers, and change where clause to the row id

Answer (score 1):

If $row matches to a row in a database table, it should have a unique id.  You can pass that unique id in a hidden input in the form:

```php
<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?= htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>" />
```

Then in `Update.php`, reference `$_POST['id']` rather than `$_SESSION['id']`